# How to combine the results of different metrics and generate a score out of them?

Tags: python, metrics, auc

I have the following dataframe that shows the performance of my 6 models using different metrics.
I want to generate a score out of the result of all the metrics, and then detect the best model. 
I can't use average because the metrics are not in the same direction. (For example higher AUC is better but on the other hand lower MAE,MSE, and RMSE are better)

```
  Model RMSE    MAE     MSE     AUC    Score
0   a   0.29    0.187   0.084   0.65     ?
1   b   0.29    0.187   0.084   0.649    ?
2   c   0.299   0.17    0.09    0.64     ?
3   d   0.308   0.149   0.095   0.663    ?
4   e   0.314   0.143   0.099   0.675    ?
5   f   0.319   0.146   0.102   0.682    ?
```

Is it reasonable if I just multiply all of them together and then multiply them by 1/AUC and use this value as the score?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your objective function and problem which you are trying to solve.

Typically the "best" model performs better than other models using some metrics, but does not perform as well in other metrics. Such as in your example, an increase in RMSE gives better AUC but worse MAE. Have a look at the scikit documentation for an extensive list of error metrics you could possibly use: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html. You will need to decide if all receive equal weights, or not.

You may wish to consider bagging, where you combine the weighted combination of all your models, instead of picking just 1 model to reduce generalization errors when dealing with out-of-sample data.

Also consider generating out-of-sample data that follows the random distribution of your trained dataset. You may find out-of-sample data generates error metrics for each model that are quite different from in-sample results, and Monte Carlo simulation of these out-of-sample tests will give you better clarity as to which model(s) and error metrics to focus on.